# Show a modal when a link is trigger

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP process that lasts long enough generating an excel file, I would like to trigger a modal appears telling the user to wait a bit.

**Here's my code**

```
  $('#export-excel').click(function(){
        this.href = this.href + location.search;
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#myModal').show();
            },
            statusCode:{
                500: function(){
                    //Error PHP
                },
                404: function(){
                    //Erreur dans ta route
                },
                200: function(){
                    $('#myModal').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**and the link is**

```
 <a id="export-excel" class="btn btn-sm btn-menu" href="{{ path('plateforme_reassort_generationexcel') }}" title="Exporte les articles filtrés au format Excel">Export Excel</a>
```

if someone got something for me that would be good !

Comment: Why you are using ajax for this issue?

Comment: `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Comment: @GM.Akbar because i guess it the simplest way to do what i need. (show a modal on generating and close it when the file is generated.)

Comment: @Iceman and $('#myModal').modal('hide'); to hide ?

Comment: @FaresElWilliams yes...

Comment: You would be better queuing the job that generates the Excel file, and have a modal pop up saying “We’ll email you when it’s ready” or similar so that the user can carry on using your site without interrupting the file generation.

Comment: @MartinBean the generating doesn't exceed few minutes(and can be few seconds too) so i don't think an email function is needed but thank you for the idea !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api): states usage as:

> ```
> $('#myModal').modal()                      // initialized with defaults
> $('#myModal').modal({ keyboard: false })   // initialized with no keyboard
> $('#myModal').modal('show')                // initializes and invokes show immediately
> ```

```
$('#export-excel').click(function(){
        this.href = this.href + location.search;
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            statusCode:{
                500: function(){
                    //Error PHP
                },
                404: function(){
                    //Erreur dans ta route
                },
                200: function(){
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

BASIC EXAMPLE:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".custom-close").on('click', function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }, 2000)
  }, 500)
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        WILL CLOSE IN 2 secs....


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: in fact i have a little issue when the modal clause this happend : http://r78i.imgup.net/ertyheae4.PNG

Comment: Put an example there, just in case

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use modal function of JQuery modal.

```
$('#export-excel').click(function(){
        this.href = this.href + location.search;
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            statusCode:{
                500: function(){
                    //Error PHP
                },
                404: function(){
                    //Erreur dans ta route
                },
                200: function(){
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is it solve your problem? if yes please vote up and accept it. thank you

Comment: in fact i have a little issue when the modal clause this happend : http://r78i.imgup.net/ertyheae4.PNG